# porblemas con setState

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

Tengo el siguiente problema y lo resumiré de manera sencilla con un ejemplo similar

aqui declaro la variable de estado "count"

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

tengo una funcion  handleInputChange:

```
const handleInputChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;

    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log(count);
}
```

Esta función la llamo en el `onChange` de un `textField` de react , lo que pasa es que el `count` siempre se me queda un paso atrás.

Por ejemplo la primera vez que escribo me imprime 0, la segunda vez entonces 1, y así sucesivamente, espero me puedan ayudar, no entiendo que pasa... , en mi code original lo que quiero es coger lo que vaya escribiendo para hacer un filter, pero la primera vez que escribo me devuelve "" , luego la segunda vez que escribo entonces la primera letra que había escrito , y así ...

Comment: puedes poner tu `jsx`? que tienes en el componente.

Comment: Tienes que tener en cuenta que el `setCount` es asíncrono y por eso en el `console.log` te sale el valor anterior. Puedes probar de renderizar el valor en tu `jsx` y verás que sale correctamente

Comment: Es correcto lo que dice @hawks , también si lo que deseas es que pase algo cuando el valor de count cambia podrías usar el hook useEffect